# Interactuando con cuadros de diálogo

Tags: jscript

Estoy queriendo escribir un JScript para editar los metadatos de un único archivo Mp3 desde un explorador de archivos con Windows 11. El script se ejecuta correctamente capturando todos los metadatos del archivo, pero los botones no funcionan, cuando los presiono se genera un error en la línea:
`case "btn_añadir_caratula" = true;`   (No se puede asignar a '[string]').

Me parece que el error se deba a la forma en que he declarado los eventos, y no a los comandos que he utilizado en ellos, pues estos los he utilizado en botones simples (sin script) y funcionan correctamente.

```jscript
//Eventos
if (msg.event == "click") { //Eventos del tipo clic
  switch (msg.control) {
    case "btn_añadir_caratula" = true;
      var coverart_usuario = dlg.open("Carátula"); //Solicitar carátula
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr' + ' META "coverart:' + coverart_usuario + '"'); //Establecer carátula
      break;

    case "btn_eliminar_caratula" = true;
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META coverart -'); //Eliminar carátula
      break;

    case "btn_eliminar_todo" = true;
      cmd.RunCommand(
        'SetAttr META track title artist album genre year comment coverart composers albumartist discnumber'
      ); //Eliminar todo
      break;

    case "btn_guardar" = true;
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "title:' + dlg.Control("titulo").label + '"');
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "artist:' + dlg.Control("artista").label + '"');
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "album:' + dlg.Control("album").label + '"');
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "year:' + dlg.Control("anio").label + '"');
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "track:' + dlg.Control("pista").label + '"');
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "genre:' + dlg.Control("genero").label + '"');
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "comment:' + dlg.Control("comentario").label + '"');
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "albumartist:' + dlg.Control("artista_album").label + '"');
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "composers:' + dlg.Control("compositor").label + '"');
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "disc:' + dlg.Control("numero_disco").label + '"');
      cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "coverart:' + dlg.Control("caratula").label + '"');

  }
}
```

**Código completo**

```javascript
    // Iniciar el script
    function OnInit(initData)
    {
        initData.name = "Mp3 Tag File";
        initData.version = "1.0";
        initData.copyright = "(c) 2024 DASOTA";
        initData.desc = "Editor Mp3 Tag de archivo único";
        initData.default_enable = true;
        initData.min_version = "13.0";
    }
    
    // Añadir comando
    function OnAddCommands(addCmdData)
    {
        var cmd = addCmdData.AddCommand();
        cmd.name = "Mp3TagFile";
        cmd.method = "OnMp3TagFile";
        cmd.desc = "";
        cmd.label = "Mp3 Tag File";
        cmd.template = "Mp3TagFile"; //Nombre del objeto Diálogo
        cmd.hide = false;
        cmd.icon = "script";
    }
    
    // Implementar el comando Mp3TagFile
    function OnMp3TagFile(scriptCmdData) {
        var dlg = scriptCmdData.func.Dlg();
        dlg.title = "Mp3 Tag File - Directory Opus";
        dlg.template = 'Mp3TagFile';
        dlg.detach = true;
        dlg.Create //Crear el diálogo
            
        //Definir la variable item
        var tab = scriptCmdData.func.sourcetab;
        var item = tab.selected_files(0);
    
        // Asignarle los valores a los controles
        dlg.Control("archivo").value = item.name_stem; //Nombre de archivo sin extensión
        dlg.Control("titulo").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3title;
        dlg.Control("artista").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3artist;
        dlg.Control("album").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3album;
        dlg.Control("anio").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3year;
        dlg.Control("pista").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3track;
        dlg.Control("genero").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3genre;
        dlg.Control("comentario").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3comment;
        dlg.Control("artista_album").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3albumartist;
        dlg.Control("compositor").value = item.metadata.audio.composers;
        dlg.Control("numero_disco").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3disc;
    
        //Contenido carátula
        if (item.metadata.audio.coverart > 0) {
            var tmpFile = DOpus.FSUtil().GetTempFile();
            tmpFile.Write(item.metadata.audio.coverart(0).data);
            tmpFile.Close();
            dlg.Control("caratula").label = Script.LoadImage(tmpFile);
        } else {
            dlg.Control("caratula").label = '';
        }
    
        //Fondo carátula (blanco)
        dlg.Control("caratula").bg = "#FFFFFF"; 
    
        //Contenido resolución  
        if (item.metadata.audio.coverart > 0) {
            var tmpFile = DOpus.FSUtil().GetTempFile();
            tmpFile.Write(item.metadata.audio.coverart(0).data);
            tmpFile.Close();
            var reso = item.metadata.audio.coverart(0);
            dlg.Control("resolucion").label = reso.width + " x " + reso.height  + " x " + reso.depth + " (" + reso.size.fmt + ")";
        } else {
            dlg.Control("resolucion").label = '';
        }
        
        //Fondo etiqueta
        dlg.Control("resolucion").fg = "#000000"; //Texto (negro)   
        dlg.Control("resolucion").bg = "#FFFFFF"; //Fondo (blanco)
    
        dlg.Show //Mostrar el diálogo
    
        while (true) { //Mientras verdadero
            msg = dlg.GetMsg(); //Mostrar el diálogo
            if (!msg.result) break; //Cuando falso, cerrar el diálogo
    
        //Establecer los eventos
        if (msg.event == "click") { //Eventos del tipo clic 
            switch (msg.control) {
          
                case "btn_anadir_caratula":
            var coverart_usuario = dlg.open("Carátula"); //Solicitar carátula
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr' + ' META "coverart:' + coverart_usuario + '"'); //Establecer carátula
                    break;
    
                case "btn_eliminar_caratula":
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META coverart -'); //Eliminar carátula
                    break;
    
                case "btn_eliminar_todo":
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META track title artist album genre year comment coverart composers albumartist discnumber'); //Eliminar todo
                    break;
    
            case "btn_guardar":
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "title:' + dlg.Control("titulo").label + '"');
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "artist:' + dlg.Control("artista").label + '"');
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "album:' + dlg.Control("album").label + '"');
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "year:' + dlg.Control("anio").label + '"');
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "track:' + dlg.Control("pista").label + '"');
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "genre:' + dlg.Control("genero").label + '"');
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "comment:' + dlg.Control("comentario").label + '"');
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "albumartist:' + dlg.Control("artista_album").label + '"');
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "composers:' + dlg.Control("compositor").label + '"');
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "disc:' + dlg.Control("numero_disco").label + '"');
          cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "coverart:' + dlg.Control("caratula").label + '"');
              }
        }
      }
    }
    
    ==SCRIPT RESOURCES
    <resources>
        <resource name="Mp3TagFile" type="dialog">
            <dialog fontsize="9" height="180" lang="esm" title="Mp3TagFile" width="332">
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="archivo_t" title="Archivo:" type="static" valign="top" width="48" x="8" y="10" />
                <control halign="left" height="12" name="archivo" readonly="yes" type="edit" width="148" x="58" y="8" />
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="titulo_t" title="Título:" type="static" valign="top" width="48" x="8" y="26" />
                <control halign="left" height="12" name="titulo" type="edit" width="148" x="58" y="25" />
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="artista_t" title="Artista:" type="static" valign="top" width="48" x="8" y="43" />
                <control halign="left" height="12" name="artista" type="edit" width="148" x="58" y="42" />
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="album_t" title="Álbum:" type="static" valign="top" width="48" x="8" y="60" />
                <control halign="left" height="12" name="album" type="edit" width="148" x="58" y="59" />
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="anio_t" title="Año:" type="static" valign="top" width="48" x="8" y="78" />
                <control halign="center" height="12" name="anio" number="yes" type="edit" updown="yes" val_min="1" width="50" x="58" y="76" />
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="pista_t" title="Pista:" type="static" valign="top" width="18" x="136" y="78" />
                <control halign="center" height="12" name="pista" number="yes" type="edit" updown="yes" val_min="1" width="30" x="157" y="76" />
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="genero_t" title="Género:" type="static" valign="top" width="48" x="8" y="94" />
                <control edit="yes" height="40" name="genero" sort="yes" type="combo" width="148" x="58" y="93">
                    <contents>
                        <item text="Romántico" />
                        <item text="Balada" />
                        <item text="Bolero" />
                        <item text="Trova" />
                        <item text="Patrio" />
                        <item text="Son" />
                        <item text="Salsa" />
                        <item text="Guaracha" />
                        <item text="Montuno" />
                        <item text="Cumbia" />
                        <item text="Merengue" />
                        <item text="Tropical" />
                        <item text="Ranchera" />
                        <item text="Reggae" />
                        <item text="Reggaetón" />
                        <item text="Hip Hop" />
                        <item text="Pop" />
                        <item text="Rock" />
                        <item text="Tecno" />
                        <item text="Electrónico" />
                        <item text="Jazz" />
                        <item text="Infantil" />
                        <item text="Religioso" />
                        <item text="Instrumental" />
                        <item text="Vocal" />
                        <item text="Efecto sonoro" />
                        <item text="Inglés" />
                        <item text="Bossa Nova" />
                        <item text="Tropicália" />
                        <item text="Samba" />
                        <item text="Pagode" />
                        <item text="Lambada" />
                        <item text="MPB" />
                        <item text="Forró" />
                        <item text="Sertanejo" />
                        <item text="Sertanejo universitário" />
                        <item text="Axé" />
                        <item text="Funk" />
                        <item text="Gospel" />
                        <item text="Brega" />
                        <item text="Choro" />
                        <item text="Frevo" />
                        <item text="Baião" />
                        <item text="Piseiro" />
                        <item text="Pisadinha" />
                    </contents>
                </control>
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="comentario_t" title="Comentario:" type="static" valign="top" width="48" x="8" y="111" />
                <control halign="left" height="12" name="comentario" type="edit" width="148" x="58" y="110" />
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="artista_album_t" title="Artista álbum:" type="static" valign="top" width="48" x="9" y="128" />
                <control halign="left" height="12" name="artista_album" type="edit" width="148" x="59" y="127" />
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="compositor_t" title="Compositor:" type="static" valign="top" width="48" x="8" y="145" />
                <control halign="left" height="12" name="compositor" type="edit" width="148" x="58" y="144" />
                <control halign="left" height="8" name="numero_disco_t" title="Número disco:" type="static" valign="top" width="48" x="8" y="162" />
                <control halign="left" height="12" name="numero_disco" type="edit" updown="yes" val_min="1" width="148" x="58" y="161" />
                <control halign="center" height="8" name="resolucion" type="static" valign="top" width="100" x="218" y="95" />
                <control height="122" name="caratula_t" title="Carátula" type="group" width="113" x="212" y="4" />
                <control halign="center" height="86" image="yes" name="caratula" type="static" valign="center" width="100" x="218" y="15" />
                <control height="14" name="btn_anadir_caratula" title="Añadir..." type="button" width="41" x="224" y="107" />
                <control height="14" name="btn_eliminar_caratula" title="Eliminar" type="button" width="41" x="272" y="107" />
                <control height="15" name="btn_eliminar_todo" title="Eliminar todo" type="button" width="76" x="229" y="135" />
                <control default="yes" height="15" name="btn_guardar" title="Guardar" type="button" width="76" x="229" y="155" />
            </dialog>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Comment: ya intentaste quitar acentos y ñ, en algunas ocasiones pueden causar conflictos

Comment: @MrDonPh0x No, nunca intenté de esa forma, voy a ver, muchas gracias.

Comment: @MrDonPh0x Apliqué tu recomendación pero los botones continúan sin responder y generando errores. La sintaxis de los eventos tiene que estar mal, pero realmente no sé mucho de eso.

Comment: No entiendo por qué en cada case estás haciendo una asignación, como si fuera que cada string es una variable (y tiene total sentido que aparezca el error _No se puede asignar a '[string]'_). Revisá la sintaxis de JScript para los switch - case.

Comment: Muchas gracias @padaleiana, voy estudiar más sobre Case y sobre la sintaxis de Switch para JScript, realmente no sé nada de programación.

Comment: Intenté modificar la sintaxis al tipo **case "btn_añadir_caratula":** pero tampoco funciona

Comment: `switch (msg.control) { case "btn_añadir_caratula":` equivaldría a un `if ("btn_añadir_caratula" == msg.control ) {` verifica que es lo que hay en `msg.control` tal vez no sea un string/texto y falla la comparación

Comment: @aloMalbarez Malbarez, gracias por tu explicación, busqué en todo el código y no aparece nada referente a `msg.control`, su única aparición es en `switch (msg.control) {`

Comment: @aloMalbarez será que puedo publicar el código completo para que me ayuden a detectar ese problema? El código es pequeño